# проблемы со сравнением строк. Проверка пароля из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, аутентификация

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая запускается только по паролю в определённом файле. Код там такой:

```
users = open('users.txt', 'r', 1)
userlist = users.readline()
i = 0
user = []
while userlist:
    password = str(userlist)
    user.insert(i, password)
    userlist = users.readline()
    i = i+1
users.close()
uid = int(input('Your id: \n'))
upassword = str(input('Your password: \n'))
print(user[uid])
if user[uid]== upassword:
    cmd = input('Hello! \n')
else:
    cmd = input('Incorrect password.\n>')
```

Файл с паролями выглядит так:

```
1234
5678
```

По идее, если ввести сначала 0, а потом 1234— то он должен показать "Hello!", но он показывает "Incorrect password". При этом, такая же пара 1-5678 распознаётся правильно. Что делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы считываете файл построчно, но там присутствует перенос строки "\n". Вы этот момент не учитываете. Для очистки строк от лишних и непечатных символов используйте, например, функцию [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html)

В Вашем коде одним из способов будет изменить строку

```
if user[uid] == upassword:
```

на

```
if user[uid].strip() == upassword:
```

хотя это и не очень красиво. Но тут встаёт вопрос о качестве представленного кода.

Answer (score 6):

Код в вопросе можно переписать как:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

passwords = Path('users.txt').read_text().splitlines()
uid = int(input('Your id: \n'))
upassword = input('Your password: \n').strip()
msg = 'Hello!' if passwords[uid] == upassword else 'Incorrect password.'
print(msg)
```

Хотя хранить пароли открытым текстом на диске не хорошо, даже вводить пароль открытым текстом не безопасно, и запоминать пользователям их `uid` не очень удобно.

Можно хранить только хэш пароля и имя пользователя вместо номера спрашивать. К примеру, чтобы сравнить пароль, хранимый в `/etc/passwd`, используя [`crypt` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#examples):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pwd
import crypt
import getpass
from hmac import compare_digest as compare_hash

def login():
    username = input('Your user name: ').strip()
    cryptedpasswd = pwd.getpwnam(username)[1]
    if cryptedpasswd:
        if cryptedpasswd == 'x' or cryptedpasswd == '*':
            raise ValueError('no support for shadow passwords')
        cleartext = getpass.getpass()
        return compare_hash(crypt.crypt(cleartext, cryptedpasswd), cryptedpasswd)
    else:
        return True # no password
```

Если пароль для желаемого пользователя хранится в `/etc/shadow` тогда [можно использовать `spwd.getspnam()[1]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/spwd.html), чтобы хэш пароля получить,  и запускать скрипт от пользователя, который это файл может читать (root, группа shadow).

Чтобы получить хэш пароля:

```
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt('p4$$wOrd')
'$6$NR7pbExWXdzpEti/$3rIzv5vmkvriZie0Hu9Y1n3uCtBdqICn32WCdtfSKzsHFJSBvrPVNhfCuRYX8PwE/gJ8ORW.PurdXlUy1BbGS0'
```

Чтобы сохранить в свой файл:

```
>>> hashed_passwd = crypt.crypt('p4$$wOrd')
>>> username = 'john'
>>> with open('users.txt', 'a') as file:
...     file.write(f'{username}:{hashed_passwd}\n')
```

Чтобы прочитать и проверить пароль:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import crypt
import getpass
from hmac import compare_digest as compare_hash
from pathlib import Path

def login():
    username = input('Your user name: ').strip()
    cryptedpasswd = next((passwd
                          for line in Path('users.txt').read_text().splitlines() 
                          for user, passwd in [line.partition(':')[::2]]
                          if user == username), None)
    if cryptedpasswd is not None:
        cleartext = getpass.getpass()
        return compare_hash(crypt.crypt(cleartext, cryptedpasswd), cryptedpasswd)
    else:
        return False # user not found

msg = 'Hello!' if login() else 'Wrong credentials.'
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже дан. Предложу свою версию. Может автору будет интересно.

```
users = open('users.txt', 'r')
def init():
    index = 0
    users_list = []
    for add in users.readlines():
        users_list.insert(index, add)
        index += 1
    ID = int(input('Enter ID: '))
    Password = str(input('Enter PASSWORD: '))
    if users_list[ID].strip() == Password:
        return True
    return False
init()
```

Или так:

```
users = open('users.txt', 'r')
def init():
    users_list = [add.strip() for add in users.readlines()]
    ID = int(input('Enter ID: '))
    Password = str(input('Enter PASSWORD: '))
    if users_list[ID] == Password:
        return True
    return False
```

Как писал человек выше. Вопрос о качестве.