# Некорректный вывод данных при проверке пароля из sqlite БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, аутентификация

В БД храниться 2 строки с данными

1. login = admin, password = admin
2. login = Twiss, password = 2332c623

при выполнения данного кода

```
import sqlite3
a = input('логин')
b = input('пароль')
conn = sqlite3.connect('client.db')
try:
    sql = "SELECT Login, Password, Surname FROM authentication"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        if a in str(row[0]):
            if b in str(row[1]):
                print('Авторизован')
            else:
                print("Не верный пароль")
        else:
            print("Не верный логин")
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Если вводить login = Twiss, password = 2332c623, выводится значение не верный логин и авторизован, а если вводить login = admin, password = admin то все в порядке. Как сделать так чтобы при вводе других данных кроме admin выводилось  только авторизован  и работало чтобы по логике авторизации

Comment: выводить сообщение "неверный логин" надо по окончании цикла, если верный не был найден. А сейчас вы что-нибудь выводите для каждой строки

Comment: @splash58 не совсем понятно как это реализовать можете на примере этого кода описать

Comment: Написал что-то, похожее на питоновский код :)

Comment: вы в образовательных целях код пишите? Если нет, то используйте готовые библиотеки для auth. В вашем коде куча проблем (зачем показывать на экране пароль (используйте getpass вместо input) Зачем пароль открытым текстом хранить? (хотя бы crypt используйте) Зачем в Питоне цикл писать, вместо проверки в БД? (база данных поддерживает поиск, используйте её возможности) И по мелочи: цикл не рабочий (попробуйте встроенные функции all, any реализовать, чтобы освоиться), ненужные str, `__getitem__` вызовы. try/finally у вас вместо with конструкции. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630947/23044)

Comment: @jfs можете написать как лучше сделать без косяков

Comment: по ссылке пример есть. Но как я уже сказал, сами не пишите, а используйте готовые компоненты. К примеру, если веб-приложение на flask пишите, посмотрите из чего Flask-Security составлено.

Comment: @jfs а как  саму реализацию поиска  в базе сделать. Как я понимаю есть вариант это в самой базе сделать а потом вывести? Или уже стоит другой вопрос задвать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы проверить имя пользователя и пароль, хранящиеся в sqlite базе данных:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3
from crypt import crypt
from getpass import getpass
from secrets import compare_digest as compare_hash


def authenticated():
    with sqlite3.connect('client.db') as db:
        name = input('Your user name: ').strip()
        [password_hash] = next(db.execute(
            'select password_hash from users where name = ?', [name]), [None])
    if password_hash:
        password = getpass()
        return compare_hash(crypt(password, password_hash), password_hash)
    else:  # no user
        return False


print(authenticated())
```

- используется select + where, чтобы найти запись по имени пользователя, вместо цикла в Питоне
- в базе хранится хэш пароля с затравкой, а не сам пароль открытым текстом
- при вводе пароля он не показывается — `getpass()` вместо `input()`

Это устраняет некоторые проблемы с вашим кодом. В вопросах доступа и предоставления полномочий, лучше готовыми решениями пользоваться, которые соответствуют вашей ситуации по отношению удобство/риск использования.