# Записать в файл 32 случайных цифры

Tags: python

Как дописать правильно код python? Надо зациклить это , чтобы результат сохранялся в файл.

```
import random
psw = ''
for x in range(32):
    psw = psw + random.choice(list('0123456789'))

print(psw)
```

Comment: Почитайте книжку по Питону, про циклы и файловые операции.

Comment: Читаю и не могу сообразить ,так итак пробовал ((((

Comment: Надо не пробовать, а понимать.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что должно сохранятся в файл?

Comment: числа которые будут генерироваться. И как установить ограничение по количеству вывода строк результата

Comment: @Дима ха-ха, а сколько в Вашем понимании в строке символов? Для сохранения в файл - сейчас напишу.

Comment: 32 символа я так понимаю должно быть в строке

Comment: @Дима с чего вы вы взяли? Это нигде не задокументировано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот:

```
open("output.txt", "w").write('\n'.join(map(lambda _: ''.join(__import__('random').choice('0123456789') for _ in range(32)), range(int(input('n: '))))))
```

Comment: output,txt создает 32 строки с одной цифрой

Comment: А надо ,чтобы создал n-ое количество строк , в каждой строке 32 символа

Comment: поправил........

Comment: Спасибо большое все работает!!!

Comment: Извините за наглость...А как скрипт можно изменить ,чтобы число  строк задать в скрипте , а не в терминале?

Comment: Сам разобрался)))

Comment: я конечно все понимаю, но зачем делать все в одну строчку? это же не shortest-соревнование. А для понимания, я считаю, лучше использовать переменные.

Comment: это необходимо для того что бы вы сами разобрались как работает код. Т.е. вы не можете его прочитать -> разбиваете на компоненты -> происходит понимание кода.

Comment: @Денис  Можете написать с переменными, это будет очень полезно.

Comment: @Andrio Skur  Как сделать вывод результатов в терминале не сохраняя в файл?

Comment: заменить `open("output.txt", "w").write` на `print`

Answer (score 2):

Сохраняем каждое сгенерированное число в файл(каждая строка - новое число):

```
import random
psw = random.choice(list('123456789'))
count = int(input("Count: "))
out = open("output.txt", "w")
for x in range(count):
    psw = psw + random.choice(list('0123456789'))
    out.write(psw)
out.close()
```

Comment: Как теперь сделать так что бы он генерировал n-ое количество строк без остановки?

Comment: Изменил его в такой формат        [`code  import random
psw=""
for x in range(32):
  psw = psw+random.choice(list('0123456789'))
out = open("snake.txt", "w")
out.write(psw)
out.close() `]

Comment: чтобы повторял этот скрипт и записывал результат .txt

Comment: @Дима изменил код, теперь n-ое количество.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import string
from pathlib import Path

random_digits = ''.join([random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(32)])
Path('random32.txt').write_text(random_digits)
```

Если строка должна быть секретной, то используйте [`secrets.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice)(тяжелее результат предсказать) и конечно не записывайте секреты открытым текстом в файл (можно [записать хэш пароля с затравкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630947/23044)).

Чтобы `n` таких строк записать:

```
with open('random32.txt', 'w') as file:
    for _ in range(n):
        random_digits = ''.join([random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(32)])
        print(random_digits, file=file)
```

Если большое `n` и есть ограничение по времени, то можно ускорить [на пару порядков](https://gist.github.com/zed/a66866c01beab98ce1228138b4c439f4): [Fastest method to generate big random string with lower Latin letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16308989/4279).

Comment: Как быть если захочу с цифрами использовать буквы?

Comment: @Дима `string.digits + string.ascii_letters` Если самостоятельно решение с + не приходит в голову, то стоит любое вводное руководство по Питону посмотреть, чтобы иметь представления какие возможности Питон предоставляет.  Если это всё равно сложности вызывает, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос с самой маленькой задачей, на которой вы застряли (не стоит рассказывать о задаче из многих шагов, если этого можно избежать). Мне интересны подобные вопросы (они относятся к категории вещей, которые  я мог забыть что я их знаю "things I don't know that I know").